# write .net 4 code to compile as desktop and web applications

Tags: .net

is it possible to write code in .net 4 and compile it to create both web and desktop applications in the same time?

I have to support a web version and a desktop version of an application and would like to write one version of code and compile it as a web version which works on the web (browers and web server) and also a desktop application which would work on the desktop for non web based clients. Both apps should be doing more or less the same thing and same interfaces.

I can understand there would be limitaions but is it possible?

Please also post any links with tutorials if you have any.

Comment: Probably you can share **most of your non UI code** (with some limitations and/or precautions) but you can't share the user interface itself (web applications run on IIS, desktop application don't). Technologies for UI are pretty different (WPF/WinForms for desktop and ASP.NET on web) and can't be exchanged. You may _consider_ **Silverlight** if you want to reuse UI too (see for example what Visual Studio LightSwitch does).

Comment: Business and data layers can be common but the UI code cannot be shared.  How same do the interfaces need to be?  What does the app do?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *solution* that does that, with 3 projects:

- 1 class-library for the core objects, logic, data-access, etc
- 1 windows-exe for the windows UI
- 1 web-application for the web UI

however, it wouldn't be practical to try and shoe-horn the web and windows UI into the same project: the project structure and build output is necessarily different between the two

Answer (score 0):

This entirely depends on the nature of your application.  If you need to build a windows form application then obviously this cannot be directly converted to a web application.

You can maybe use Silverlight to create an application that runs both on the desktop and in the browser. Read more about [Silverlight at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/silverlight/bb187401.aspx).

The other alternative is to write an n-tier application; with a UI for the web and a separate one for windows that share the business logic and data.